# What happens when I ask tensorflow to calculate

Tags: tensorflow

Consider this very simple example:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = a + 2
c = b + 4

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

sess.run([b, c], feed_dict={a: 1})
```

Will tensorflow calculate `b` only one time, or two times?

Answer (score 0):

It will calculate 1 time.

TensorFlow run the calculation defined by the graph and fetch the value `[b,c]` for output.

Answer (score 0):

only one time (but I guess you knew)

[image: TensorBoard]

Answer (score 0):

*b* will be computed only once. The result will be used to calculate *c*.

Here you have a short example from [Tensorflow programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs)

```
x = tf.constant([[37.0, -23.0], [1.0, 4.0]])
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 2]))
y = tf.matmul(x, w)
output = tf.nn.softmax(y)
init_op = w.initializer

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Run the initializer on `w`.
  sess.run(init_op)

  # Evaluate `output`. `sess.run(output)` will return a NumPy array containing
  # the result of the computation.
  print(sess.run(output))

  # Evaluate `y` and `output`. Note that `y` will only be computed once, and its
  # result used both to return `y_val` and as an input to the `tf.nn.softmax()`
  # op. Both `y_val` and `output_val` will be NumPy arrays.
  y_val, output_val = sess.run([y, output])
```